# How to simulate user login into website and upload

Tags: c#, upload, watin

I have a task of uploading files automatically. It would be very easy if I had access to the webserver. Then I could use WebClient.UploadFile, but unfortunately I don't have access.  So I was thinking if I can use WatIn libraries to open IE web page and then click on the button and upload file. The problem with WatIn is that it seems that there is no solution if website requires authentication. 
Is it at all possible to do upload to the server in such a way?

Thanks in advance for response.

Elena

Comment: what kind of authentication do you need on the server ?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that there is no solution in WatiN if website requires authentication? What kind of authentication?

Answer (score 2):

You can create webrequest with network credentials so you can login to the site, download firefox and TamperData extension to see what variables are being sent to the webserver then you can create the http request based on the the post variables needed,and here its an article about creating secured webrequest

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetWebRequest/dotnetWebRequest.htm

and here a guide on how to use tamperdata

http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tamper_Data

hope this helps

Alex

Comment: But if for example use HttpWebRequest to post file, I need to have some hadler on server which will take this file and save it in file system. Am I right?

Comment: ok, let me see if understand your issue correctly, you have a web interface to upload files to that server (ie a web file manager, cpanel file manager, or any other web interface to upload to a web server) wich you can open with internet explorer and upload yourself a file right?

Comment: if the above statement its true you just need to check what parameters are being sent to the server when you clic the upload button and create the webrequest by hand using the httpwebrequest class or the webclient and send the POST parameters nedded

Comment: Yes I have web interface, but I don't have have access to it's code and I don't have access to web server whre this application is installed. So I can't modify it. I have access to the web interface as user. And I can upload file now by clicking button "Browse" and then by clicking "Import" button which sends file to web server. So I'm interested if it is possible to post file to the server without touching this existing application

Comment: And i can check these parameters using this Tamper tool or Fiddler. yes?

Comment: Yes, you can :) you dont need access to the server nor the sourcecode, you just need to see what request and POST/GET parameters the Import button its sending to the server and then create your own request with those params, (you would be kinda simulating a click on the import button since http communication its based on requests and responses) hope this helps Alex

Answer (score 1):

If you have ftp access you could use one of the FTP Comercial controls

Answer (score 0):

> It would be very easy if I had access
>   to the webserver.

If the web server is accessible to you using Internet Explorer (other browsers are available) then you can run a program from the same location that utilises `WebClient`.

Comment: The web server is accessible only via web application. The problem is that that I need on Web server some handler which will take my file and save it and I don't know where files are posted now. Maybe I can use some tool as Fiddler to look in webRequests and i will be able to see url of the file handler